# Api endpoint requires string, how to find what strings can be used?

Tags: ruby, api, syntax, rubygems

I'm using Ruby and a gem for [app_store_connect](https://rubygems.org/gems/app_store_connect/versions/0.23.0). I'm trying to create a profile. From the readme, I can configure my client like so

```
AppStoreConnect.config = {
  issuer_id: 'issuer_id',
  key_id: 'key_id',
  private_key: File.read(File.new("/Path/AuthKey.p8"))
}

app_store_connect = AppStoreConnect::Client.new
```

And I have that setup and successfully working. I've tested with with the `create_bundle_id()` function which is properly updating my AppStoreConnect account. I've also found that I can call the following to get a list of all profiles.

```
app_store_connect.profiles
```

[Github](https://github.com/kyledecot/app_store_connect) seems to indicate that I can call the function `create_profile()` which requires strings for `name` and `profile_type` in order to create a new profile. So in my code, I run

```
app_store_connect.create_profile(
  name: "Foo"
  profile_type: "IOS_APP_STORE"
)
```

But no matter what I do, I can't seem to make this one work. I'm not sure what's failing or how to check either. I got the string for `profile_type` from checking other profiles, but I can't help but feel like I'm missing something. Is there a chance I could get some help figuring what I'm missing or what the proper string should be?

For context, I'm very new to ruby and I don't know what tools are available to make this language work for me. So far, it's mostly been trial and error.

Comment: Your problems here have very little to do with the actual programming languge. You need to [study the documentation for the API](https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/api/) your using to see what options it expects. When working with API clients in any language you have to remember that they are often just thin wrappers around API calls and won't actually have detailed documentation of the endpoints of the API.

Comment: That’s good to know. Been a lot to learn with this as I’ve never used jwt and it appears that’s how Apple does all their appStoreConnect api calls. I’ve been tempted to write my own just for a little more clarity but I think I’d end up doing a less well done job than what’s already being presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you're not actually missing the commas when you call `create_profile`.

> But no matter what I do, I can't seem to make this one work. I'm not sure what's failing or how to check either.

It always helps to include the error/response you are seeing!

> what the proper string [for `profile_type`] should be?

Unfortunately, this gem seems to be somewhat poorly documented. In that kind of situation, I dive into the source code of the gem to attempt to understand how it works (I understand that this can be intimidating when you have less experience, but it can be a great way to learn!). I searched for `create_profile`, and [this `schema.json` was the only result](https://github.com/kyledecot/app_store_connect/blob/5de175cad7253f849b725f309572b1cd488befed/lib/config/schema.json#L96). The fact that there is no plain method definition for `create_profile` indicates to me that it gets defined through metaprogramming, from that schema. In that case, I would assume the API payload is sent through unmodified. In Googling the associated API endpoint URL from the schema, `api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/profiles`, I found [Apple's docs for it](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/create_a_profile). Clicking through from there leads to [this list of values for the profile type](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/profilecreaterequest/data/attributes).

Comment: I’ve spent the last day diving into the source code like you mention. It’s tough to chew, especially at my level with Ruby. I didn’t realize meta programming was a thing that’s even possible. I appreciate the guidance. It’s been hard to feel lost on all this.